# Been having issue with "Error: 'MenuController' is imported"

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I keep having this issue while I try to compile my flutter application

`lib/view/screens/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart:7:1: Error: 'MenuController' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/menu_anchor.dart' and 'package:vale_ace_boy/controller/menu_controller.dart'. import 'package:vale_ace_boy/controller/menu_controller.dart';`

How can I get this solved please

I've tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably created a class/widget called MenuController, which [already exists](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuController-class.html) in Flutter, so there is ambiguity between the two of them.

Rename your MenuController as something else, for example `CustomMenuController`.

Comment: Thank.you so much!! Worked just like magic